# Ionic iOS Keyboard Causing Footer To Snap Up

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I have an object for a little chat app. When the input is focused on this footer, the keyboard triggers and after the keyboard has fully shown, the footer then jarringly snaps to the top of the keyboard.

So the footer isn’t hidden after the keyboard has fully moved up, but it is not a good experience because snapping feels awkward.

Is there a way to make my footer smoothly move with the iOS keyboard?

The html of the page is basically this:

```
<ion-page>
  <ion-content>
  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer>
    <my-input></my-input>
  </ion-footer>
</ion-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

ion-inputs handle this keyboard interaction. Maybe you can try using an ion-input & see if it solves your problem.

I have implemented an imperfect solution where I listen to Keyboard open & close events and then scroll the Ion-content accordingly. Here's the code for the directive:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, NgModule, OnDestroy, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { IonContent, Platform } from "@ionic/angular";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";

const SCROLL_DELAY = 100;
const TOOLBAR_HEIGHT = 44; // todo Can be different for some pages

@Directive({
  selector: "[appInputScrollIntoView]",
})
export class InputScrollIntoViewDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input("appInputScrollIntoView") content: IonContent;
  keyboardHeight: number = 0;
  target: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLSelectElement;
  focused = false;
  closed$ = new Subject();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private platform: Platform) {}

  @HostListener("focus", ["$event"])
  onFocus(event: Event) {
    this.focused = true;
  }

  @HostListener("focusout", ["$event"])
  onFocusOut(event: Event) {
    this.focused = false;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.target = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLSelectElement;

    // Android handles keyboard scenario on HTML automatically
    const matchPlatform = this.platform.is("ios") && this.platform.is("capacitor");
    if (!matchPlatform) return;

    this.platform.keyboardDidShow.pipe(takeUntil(this.closed$)).subscribe((ev) => {
      const { keyboardHeight } = ev;
      this.keyboardHeight = keyboardHeight;
      this.adjustScrollPosition();
    });

    this.platform.keyboardDidHide.pipe(takeUntil(this.closed$)).subscribe(() => {
      this.keyboardHeight = 0;
      // maybe move back to original position here..
    });
  }

  adjustScrollPosition() {
    if (!this.focused) {
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.scrollUpIfBehindKeyboard();
      this.scrollDownIfBehindSafeArea();
    }, 50);
  }

  scrollUpIfBehindKeyboard() {
    const windowHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0);
    const targetHeightFromBottom = windowHeight - this.target.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    const requiredScroll = this.keyboardHeight - targetHeightFromBottom;
    if (requiredScroll > 0) {
      this.content.scrollToPoint(0, this.keyboardHeight, SCROLL_DELAY);
    }
  }

  scrollDownIfBehindSafeArea() {
    const safeArea = +getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
      .getPropertyValue("--ion-safe-area-top")
      .replace("px", "");
    const headerHeigth = TOOLBAR_HEIGHT;
    const top = this.target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const requiredScroll = safeArea + headerHeigth - top;
    if (requiredScroll > 0) {
      const y = this.target.offsetHeight - safeArea - headerHeigth;
      this.content.scrollToPoint(0, y, SCROLL_DELAY);
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.closed$.next();
    this.closed$.complete();
  }
}
```